# Unable to disable location service in IOS application after changing View

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, location-services

I'm trying to get Location manager to stop track the location of the user when the user changes the view, since i only need to show the user location on Google maps view in the first tab only.

**Im trying to enable location manager in the following way :**

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewWillAppear(animated)
      navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)

      // get location manager if dissapepared
      if self.locationManager == nil {
        checkLocationServices()
      }
  }

// check if location services is working
func checkLocationServices(){
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
        // set up
        setupLocationService()
        checkLocationAuthoization()
    }else{
        showAlert("Location services not available", "Please enable location services!")
    }
}

private func setupLocationService(){
    self.locationManager = CLLocationManager() // LocationServices.getLocationManager()

    // set delegate to viewcontroller here
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    // efficient location usage 
    self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true

    self.locationManager.activityType = .otherNavigation

    // enable background update - crashed application
    // locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
}

private func checkLocationAuthoization() {
    // Request location authorization
    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            // Do mapp stuff
            break
        case .denied:
            // show alert instructing on how to turn on permissions
            showAlert("Activate location", "Please allow Flype applciation to use your location.")
            break
        case .notDetermined:
            self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            break
        case .restricted:
            break
        case .authorizedAlways:
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            break
        default:
            break
    }
}

// called every time location changed
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations.last
    customMap.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (location?.coordinate.longitude)! , zoom: 15.0)
    customMap.animate(to: customMap.camera)
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

**And I'm trying to turn it off in the following way:**

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if self.locationManager != nil {
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingHeading()
        self.locationManager = nil
        print("SET LOCATION TO NIL!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to stop location updates you should call `stopUpdatingLocation` and not `stopUpdatingHeading`. So change

```
if self.locationManager != nil {
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingHeading()
        self.locationManager = nil
        print("SET LOCATION TO NIL!")
}
```

With

```
self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
```

Comment: I have already done that in the end of didUpdateLocations, but nevertheless I added that where you suggested. However the location arrow still appears all the time in other views and if I understand correctly, it should disappear whenever the application is no longer using location services.

Comment: What do you mean by saying location arrow?

Comment: I mean the location arrow in the status bar, which should disappear when the application stops tracking the user location.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()` is enough to stop location updates. This is a nice way to save power.

Comment: I have already done that in the end of didUpdateLocations, but nevertheless I added that where you suggested. However the location arrow still appears all the time in other views.

Comment: @DaniKurkees Do you mean location arrow on the status bar?
I prefer requestwhenInuseauthorization() instead of requestAlwaysAuthorization(), I am not sure if the arrow will go away.

Comment: Yes exactly I mean the location arrow in the status bar. Should it not disappear when the app stops tracking the user?

Comment: @DaniKurkees Yes it has to be disappeared when stop tracking. 
I just checked `requestwhenInuseauthorization() ` is working fine.
Its fulfil your requirement.

Comment: I tried that too but it is not working. The current code will track the user location only once since I stopp updating location in didUpdateLocations function. However when I change view the location arrow still appears in status bar for some reason.

Comment: It won't reflect immediately, take some time to disappear on status bar.

Comment: I thought so too, however the location arrow appears in the status bar as long as I'm using the application